# How to write PHP codes usable both for http and ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, performance

I have some php codes, and there is a condition which declare type of ajax. Now I want to know, should I write all php codes for each request separately? In other word, should I write all php codes twice *(almost repeatedly)* for both methods?

```
if(!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) && strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) === "xmlhttprequest")
{
    // I'm ajax  
    $arr = array('key1'=>'value1', 'key2'=>'value2');
    echo json_encode($arr);

} else {

    // I'm not ajax
    $arr = array('key1'=>'value1', 'key2'=>'value2');
    $_SESSION["arr"] = arr;
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); // redirect to previous page
}
```

So, as you see, I have to write all PHP code twice. One time for regular request and one time for ajax request. In reality there is a lot of codes, Maybe 1000 lines of code that I have two write them again for ajax requests *(while they are almost identical)*. Is this a normal way?

Also I want to know, is there any succinct approach? Actually I like to use a approach which needs to php code just one time for both requests ...!

Comment: No, you don't have to write all of your code twice.  In general you would extract common functionality away from the UI-bound functionality.  Then you would have two different UI components (one for AJAX/API requests, one for page/UI requests, since it doesn't make much sense to keep them on the same page) which would reference the common functionality.

Comment: @David Thanks for your comment. I understand what is your point almost. But actually still I can't use it ..! Is there any small example? I want to use it as my pattern ..

Comment: Another way of thinking about it - write the functions to extract the data to an array. Then write a couple of functions to format that data - one for `HTML` output and another one for `AJAX`.

Comment: @RyanVincent seems good. May you please write a answer under my question ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a class to handle those request and put common code right into a method used by both contexts:

```
// file: class.handler.php
class contextHandler() {
  public function handleHttp() {
    $this->handleGeneral();
    // What ever has to be done in this context
    $_SESSION["arr"] = arr;
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  }

  public function handleAjax() {
    $this->handleGeneral();
    // What ever has to be done in this context
    echo json_encode($arr);
  }

  private function handleGeneral() {
    // put common code here
    $arr = array('key1'=>'value1', 'key2'=>'value2');
  }
}
```

In your code you could then use that class:

```
include 'class.handler.php';
$handler = new contextHandler();
if(
  !empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) &&
  strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) === "xmlhttprequest"
)
{
  $handler->handleAjax();
} else {
  $handler->handleHttp();
}
```

This has of course to be adjusted to your concrete needs but offers a nice and clean way of reusing code and generating small and readable code.

Comment: Thanks! I got some idea from your answer. +1